# How to get count of active asp.net stat service session count - active in last 60 minutes

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, session-state, windows-server

I am using asp.net 4.5 with asp.net state service as sessions state.

```
State server
tcpip=127.0.0.1:42112
```

Currently the active session time limit is 60 minutes.

So how can i get active sessions in last 60 minutes ? Using windows server 2012 and asp.net 4.5 with c#

thank you